# sass / css - reverse animation when a class is removed

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, css-animations

I have the following setup in css / sass:

```
@mixin animation ($stuff ) {
    -webkit-animation: $stuff;
    -moz-animation: $stuff;
    -ms-animation: $stuff;
    animation: $stuff;
}

@include keyframes (fadeIn) {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@include keyframes (fadeOut) {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.element {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  @include animation(fadeIn .5s);
}

.element.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This works to fade the opacity up, but fails to fade the opacity back down when the class is removed. I tried adding @include animation(fadeIn .5s); to element.active but it just made things screwy on both ends.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use `transition` instead of `animation`? Have `opacity: 0` on `.element`, `opacity: 1` on `.active` and set `transition: opacity .5s` on `.element`.

As for the display part on removal, you need to make use of the [**`transitionend`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event and switch to `display: none` only then.

Also, you don't need `-ms-animation`. IE10 supports animations and transitions unprefixed while IE9 does not support them at all.

```js
var toggleButton = document.querySelector('button'), 
    elem = document.querySelector('.element');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(!elem.classList.contains('display')) {
    elem.classList.add('display'); 
  }
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.toggle('alpha');
  }, 150);
}, false);

elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
  if(!elem.classList.contains('alpha')) {
    elem.classList.remove('display');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.element {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s
}

.alpha { opacity: 1; }

.display { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class='element'>boo</div>
<button>toggle</button>
```